I am a Devotee of Lord Krishna. Why Krishna made me Ugly looking? Everyone Bullies me for my Looks and dark colour
I am a Devotee of Lord Krishna. Krishna himself is so handsome but Why Krishna made me Ugly. Everyone Bullies me for my Looks and dark colour

Due to previous misdeeds. Practice brahmacharya and maintain clean habits and sanga. No one will be able to come in front of you without your permission. You can also become a better devotee of Krishna.

those who bully you, you should ofc take neccesary steps like talking to parents, teachers and so on. But consider and think this for moment. Are you the body ? Or you are separate from body and witness to activities of body ? Raman Maharishi will give you answers

Your Lord was also dark-skinned. You are also dark-skinned. Why complaining? Be happy.

Because of our karma we are what we are not because of god you should live with brahmacharya do naam jap and listen to satsang of a true saint
In the shiva purana(8.23.39)it is said  :-
अवश्यमेवं भोक्तव्यं कृतं कर्म शुभाशुभम्
Which means we will have to pay for our good or bad deeds
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc399312.html
However if you dont want to pay for all of them there is another priciple that is
सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज ।
अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा श‍ुच:
Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.
https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/18/66/

This answer has no references. Can you please add some from scriptures?
